# Can Browsers on iOS use Content Blocking?

Tags: ios, web-browser, adblock

Can any of the third party browsers use the content blockers that are available in Safari? Is this an API limitation?

For example none of the browsers like Firefox or DuckDuckGo apper to use the filters from [AdGuard](https://apps.apple.com/at/app/adguard-adblock-privacy/id1047223162?l=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe not, unfortunately. If you ask [BlockBear](https://blockbear.com/faq.html) (the add filter I personally use):

> Nope. Apple limits the content blocker to Safari at the moment, only Mr. Cook knows the future.